# Is ntp.ubuntu.com impacted by GPSD bug?

Tags: ntp

We are time-syncing several instances with the `ntp.ubuntu.com` time server and have come to know about the potential GPSD issue which is relevant next sunday October 24, 2021:

> "On October 24, 2021, some time-keeping systems are going to take a
> trip back in time to March 2002, unless you update your GPSD
> programs." - [www.zdnet.com](https://www.zdnet.com/article/thanks-to-a-nasty-gpsd-bug-real-life-time-travel-trouble-arrives-this-weekend/)

This GPSD daemon could thus affect `ntp.ubuntu.com` if they are using the impacted versions of GPSD.

Anybody knows if this is the case?

Comment: ntp.ubuntu.com is Stratum 2, so I don't see what Ubuntu can do about it, as the article says it's a problem for Stratum 1.

Comment: And even if it would not be Stratum 2 - the issue is already fixed in August via bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gpsd/+bug/1938730 so unless they'd run outdated packages (which they do not) it would not occur.